# DatePicker: Value for value cannot be cast from String to Double

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, react-hooks, react-native

I am trying to learn how to use a DatePicker on React-Native. I found this code on the internet and tried it on my App.js:

https://aboutreact.com/react-native-datepicker/

The code from the link ran with no problems but the `DatePicker` they used was deprecated. So I changed the import from `react-native-datepicker` to `@react-native-community/datetimepicker` and turned the class component into a function with the use of `React Hooks`.

However, it returns the error:

```
Value for value cannot be cast from String to Double.
```

This is the `App.js`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native';
import DatePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';

export default function MyDatePicker(props){
  const [date, setDate] = useState("22-06-2020");

  function handleDate(date) {
    setDate(date)
  }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <DatePicker
          style={{width: 200}}
          value={date} //initial date from state
          mode="date" //The enum of date, datetime and time
          placeholder="select date"
          format="DD-MM-YYYY"
          minDate="01-01-2020"
          maxDate="01-01-2023"
          confirmBtnText="Confirm"
          cancelBtnText="Cancel"
          customStyles={{
            //Irrelevant
          }}
          onDateChange={handleDate}
        />

      </View>
    )
  }
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

change minDate and maxDate like following.

```
var minDate =  new Date(2020,01,01);
var maxDate = new Date(2023,01,01);
```

Comment: I did that sir but it returns the error: "Legacy octal literals are not allowed in strict mode"

Comment: remove var keyword.

Comment: minDate =  new Date(2020,1,1);
maxDate = new Date(2023,1,1);

Comment: minDate = new Date(2020,1,1); maxDate = new Date(2023,1,1);  remove 0 ,it takea it as a octal litral

Comment: It gave me the initial error 'Value for value cannot be cast from String to Double'

Comment: I think this is the issue with @react-native-community/datetimepicker library. one way to solve it use moment library and javascript to parse date.

Comment: minDate = moment('01/12/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY', true).format()
"2016-12-01T00:00:00-06:00"

Comment: The expo client went down

Comment: did you install movment

Comment: Yes sir I did install